# How to configure python interpretor in sublime text 2 to make it function as IDLE python shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext2, interpreter, python-idle

I believe other people might have asked similar questions, I don't know if I'm cross posting this, if so, I apologize and will be very appreciated for some hints or links that can guide me through this.

I'm new to sublime text2 but have being using IDLE for python scripting for a while.

The question here is quite simple. so here is the thing.

In IDLE, after I wrote a script and run it with **F5**, the script will run in a python shell like this:
[image]

and I was able to retrieve some of the avriables I defined in my script that was running after the shell finish running the script like this: adm_pop is a dict type I defined in my script.
[image]

this is very handy since every time I ran the script I was able to check whether one or two variables were declared correct and value assigned to it is correct. But in sublime text I wasn't able to do this since after the script finished running it just finished. like this:
[image]
I wasn't able to do any other input with the console like I can do with IDLE. It's just bugging me a lot so hopely you guys can give me some hints. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Have you looked into `SublimeREPL`? It opens up an interpreter and with a few keystrokes, you can copy your file over to the interpreter and run it and then check the variables afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! @Sukrit Kalra. I'm trying **SublimeREPL** right now, but encountered a little bit problem. My python.exe is not in the system path, using 64bit Windows, and for security reason I won't be able to add it into the path. When I'm try to use **REPL** to run the current file, it gave me an error "WindowsError(2,'The system cannot find the file specified.')". Kinda stuck here, trying to understand how to configure my **REPL** settings. any hints? Thanks again!

Comment: I can't seem to think of any other way. SublimeREPL works by calling python, if it's not present in the PATH, then it'll always throw that error. Why can't you add it to the path?

Comment: I don't have the administrative account on the computer I'm working one. sad though...But thanks I finally got it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `Packages` folder by selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. Go to the `User` folder and create a `SublimeREPL` folder containing a `config` folder containing a `Python` folder. Then, within that final folder save the following as `Main.sublime-menu`:

```json
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python",
                     "id": "repl_python3",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["c:/pythonXX/python.exe", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "c:/whichever/path/you/want",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            }]
        }
]
```

Change the path in `"cmd"` to the correct one for your Python installation, and feel free to customize the `"cwd"` (Current Working Directory) path to whatever you want. This will create a new menu option under `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python` that will be protected from any package upgrades.

Comment: I got it work this time, but still, how can I run my python file with this python console. I tried it, it opens up a python shell but how can I run my .py file with it? I'm still learning sublime, kind appreciate any help.

Comment: Check out the [github page](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) and the [docs](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It'll tell you how to transfer files to running REPLs.